# How to attach image and Text in email inside Html format in android?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-activity

I am Using Following code to attach Image and Text in  email  .

```
private void friends_email_share() {

    // send Email to Bob to notify site
    Log.i("Send email", "");
    String mail_body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>\n" +
            "    <p>Hi,</p>\n" +
            "    <p>Check out <b>Some dummy Text</p>\n" +
            "    <p>Some dummy Text  Some dummy Text Some dummy Text.</p>\n" +
            "    <p>Some dummy Text Some dummy TextSome dummy Text Some dummy Text</p>\n" +
            "    <p>Some dummy TextSome dummy TextSome dummy Text</p>\n" +
            "</body></html>";
    String[] TO = {};
    String[] CC = {};
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Bob Halstead's Coral Sea Fish Guide");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "" + "\n" + Html.fromHtml(mail_body));

    String image_path = "file:///assets/all_images/" + species_name + ".jpg";
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(image_path));
          try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                  Log.i("-->", "Finished sending email...");
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I am able to attach Text but not able to attach image from internal storage from assets Folder .How do I attach an Image From from assets folder for sending mail  using Gmail Intent with Intent.EXTRA_STREAM?...any kind of help would be appreciated ....thank you

Comment: As I know, You can put html only in special apps like gmail. For mail app it will not work...

Comment: are there any possibilities to send assets image via email?

Comment: Using standard mail app I think - no. Use Gmail or any other

Comment: @Alexander ,What I am trying to do is attach image from assets folder  to Gmail,I have corrected my question too ....thank you for pointing me out

Comment: I think my point is we can take image from drawable and attach to the mail.First check this one after that if you the image path from device then we can pass that path then it will take that image from device.